# Using xsl:for-each-group to select and aggregate values from an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to use xsl:for-each-group to get an average rating per user for each type.

Sample XML:

```
    <Ratings>
    <Rating name="Type1">
        <items userID="001" rating="5"/>
        <items userID="001" rating="3"/>
        <items userID="002" rating="2"/>
        <items userID="003" rating="5"/>
    </Rating>
    <Rating name="Type2">
        <items userID="002" rating="3"/>
        <items userID="003" rating="4"/>
        <items userID="003" rating="3"/>
    </Rating>
    <Rating name="Type3">
        <items userID="002" rating="5"/>
        <items userID="003" rating="5"/>
    </Rating>
</Ratings>
```

I've got as far as the XSLT below (starts with a general copy template, not shown).

```
<xsl:template match="Rating">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="averageRating">
            <xsl:value-of select="round(avg(items/@rating), 2)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="items" group-by="@userID">
            <userRating userID="{@userID}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:attribute name="averageRating">
                        <xsl:value-of select="round(avg(current()/@rating),2)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </userRating>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This gets me (seemingly?) close - each user gets listed once, and their ratings for the Type they are grouped under shows in the averageRating attribute. EXCEPT when there is more than one rating by a user within a Type, only the last rating is shown, instead of the average of all the ratings in that type by that user.

Current output:

```
    <Ratings>
    <Rating name="Type1" averageRating="3.75">
      <userRating userID="001" averageRating="3"/>
      <userRating userID="002" averageRating="2"/>
      <userRating userID="003" averageRating="5"/>
   </Rating>
    <Rating name="Type2" averageRating="3.33">
      <userRating userID="002" averageRating="3"/>
      <userRating userID="003" averageRating="3"/>
   </Rating>
    <Rating name="Type3" averageRating="5">
      <userRating userID="002" averageRating="5"/>
      <userRating userID="003" averageRating="5"/>
   </Rating>
</Ratings>
```

Desired output:

```
    <Ratings>
    <Rating name="Type1" averageRating="3.75">
      <userRating userID="001" averageRating="4"/> <!-- average of 5 and 3 -->
      <userRating userID="002" averageRating="2"/>
      <userRating userID="003" averageRating="5"/>
   </Rating>
    <Rating name="Type2" averageRating="3">
      <userRating userID="002" averageRating="3"/>
      <userRating userID="003" averageRating="3.5"/> <!-- average of 4 and 3 -->
   </Rating>
    <Rating name="Type3" averageRating="5">
      <userRating userID="002" averageRating="5"/>
      <userRating userID="003" averageRating="5"/>
   </Rating>
</Ratings>
```

When I add the value of ratings as the element value (instead of as an attribute), all ratings are shown, but as a string, ie the calculation still doesn't work, eg:

```
      <userRating userID="001">53</userRating>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    <userRating userID="{@userID}">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:attribute name="averageRating">
                    <xsl:value-of select="round(avg(current()/@rating),2)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </userRating>
```

you just want

```
<userRating userID="{@userID}" averageRating="{round(avg(current-group()/@rating),2)}">
```